# Interior of union of three sets

Tags: general-topology

i have this set: $X=B'((-2,0),1)\cup B'((2,0),1)\cup ([-1,1]\times\{0\})$

defined on $(\mathbb{R}^2,d_2),$ $B'((-2,0),1)$ is the closed ball with center (-2,0) and radius 1

How i can prove that $\overset{\circ}{X}=B((-2,0),1)\cup B((2,0),1)$ ?

And in general what is the condition on $A,B,C$ to obtain that $int(A\cup B\cup C)=int(A)\cup int(B)\cup int(C)$

Thank you

Comment: You always have $(A\cup B)^\circ\supseteq A^\circ\cup B^\circ$.  Anyway I don't understand your notatoin.  What does $B((2,0),1)$ mean exactly?

Comment: @GregoryGrant    i edited my question , B((2,0),1) is the open ball in $(\mathbb{R}^2,d_2)$ with center (2,0) and raduis 1

Comment: Ah, well you don't need the general result about unions and interiors.  You just need to show nothing in $[-1,1]\times\{0\}$ is in the interior.  If $(x,y)\in[-1,1]\times\{0\}$ then consider the sequence $x_n=(x,1/n)$.  Then $x_n$ is not in your set but its limit is.  Thus the limit cannot be in the interior.

Comment: @GregoryGrant but when we say that is because the interior of  $[-1,1]\times\{0\}$ is empty. is like we say that the interior of $X$ is the union of the interior and this is not true

Comment: @GregoryGrant are you there ?

Comment: I don't quite understand your last comment.  It's not that the interior of a union is *never* the union of the interiors, it can be true sometimes, it's just not *always* true.

Comment: Why we only see that $[-1,1]\times\{0\}=\emptyset$? how i can fined the interior of $X$ using neighborhood please @GregoryGrant

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/22639/discussion-between-vrouvrou-and-gregory-grant).

Comment: The other two parts are open balls.  You need for each $x\in B((-2,0),1)$ a neighborhood $U$ such that $x\in U\subseteq B((-2,0),1)$.  You can take $U=B((-2,0),1)$ itself since $B((-2,0),1)$ is open.  Same for the other ball.

Comment: but i don't understand you are finding the interior of each part and you make the union @GregoryGrant

Comment: No, I'm not working on the level of sets, I'm handling every point $x$ individually.  I showed that for any $x$ in the open balls, $x$ is in the interior of $X$.  And before that I showed that any $x$ in the other part is *not* in the interior.  Thus the interior is exactly the union of the two open balls.

Comment: $X$ is defined by closed ball, can you explain me mor how we write the proof , you take $x$ from $X$ ?

Comment: Oh I didn't realize it was the closed ball.  I just wrote a complete proof in the answers below but let me modify it to handle closed balls.  Give me five minutes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $D_1=\{(x,y)\mid ||(x,y),(-2,0)||\leq1\}$ and $D_2=\{(x,y)\mid ||(x,y),(2,0)||\leq1\}$ (closed balls) and $C=[-1,1]\times\{0\}$.  Let $U_1=\{(x,y)\mid ||(x,y),(-2,0)||<1\}$ and $U_2=\{(x,y)\mid ||(x,y),(2,0)||<1\}$.  Let $X=D_1\cup D_2\cup C$.  We need to show that $\overset{\circ}{X}=U_1\cup U_2$.  Let $x\in X$.  Then $x\in D_1$ or $x\in D_2$ or $x\in C$.  If $x\in D_1$ then it is either in $U_1$ or $D_1 - U_1$.  If $x$ is in $U_1$ let $U=U_1$, $U$ is open and we have $x\in U\subseteq X$.  Thus $x\in\overset{\circ}{X}$.  If $x$ is in $D_1 - U_1$ then suppose $x=(a,b)$ and $b\geq0$.  Then $(a,b+1/n)$ is not in $X$ but $(a,b+1/n)\rightarrow(a,b)$.  Thus $(a,b)\not\in \overset{\circ}{X}$.  Similarly if $b<0$ $(a,b-1/n)\rightarrow(a,b)$.  Thus the points in $D_1$ that are in $\overset{\circ}{X}$ are exactly the points in $U_1$.  By an analogous argument the points in $D_2$ that are in $\overset{\circ}{X}$ are exactly the points in $U_2$.  Now suppose $(x,0)\in C$.  Then $(x,1/n)\rightarrow (x,0)$ so there is a sequence in $X^c$ converging to $(x,0)$, so $(x,0)\not\in \overset{\circ}{X}$.  Thus $\overset{\circ}{X}=U_1\cup U_2$.

Comment: when we surch the interionr of a set we take the point x from the set or from the complete space

Comment: I start the argument with "Let $x\in X$."  Then immediately break into three cases, since $X$ us a union we know $x$ is either in $D_1$, $D_2$, or $C$.  Then I break those cases into further subcases to handle all possibilities.

Comment: I understand your question now.  I guess it depends on what your definition of interior is.  We know, for example, that $\overset{\circ}{X}$ is the largest open set in $X$.  By that definition it's obvious that $\overset{\circ}{X}\subseteq X$.  What is your definition of "interior"?

Comment: $x\in int(X)$ if and only if $X\in V_x$

Comment: You're going to have to tell me what $V_x$ is.

Comment: And do you really mean $X\in V_x$ or did you mean $x\in V_x$?

Comment: the set of neighborhood of x

Comment: Which neighborhood?  You have to be more precise please.

Comment: We say that $x\in int(X)$ when X is a nighborhood of x

Comment: Ok so in that case if $x\in\overset{\circ}{X}$ then it is immediate by the definition of interior that $x\in X$.  So you only have to consider the case $x\in X$ to determine $\overset{\circ}{X}$.